# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to BCLASSRequestPayload

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator

Here is the code that is causing me trouble tried every posible way but not able to resolve below is the detail code.

```
String businesscust=providerServiceHandler.getRequestPayload().getBusnCustomer().get(0).getBcBusnCustNum();
        long BusnCustNum=Long.parseLong(businesscust);
        String BusnCustNumHex=Long.toHexString(BusnCustNum);
        BCLASSRequestPayload bClassRequestPayload=(BCLASSRequestPayload) providerServiceHandler.getRequestPayload().getBusnCustomer();
        BusnCustomer bCLASSRequestPayload = null;
        bCLASSRequestPayload.setBcBusnCustNum(BusnCustNumHex);
        providerServiceHandler.setRequestPayload(bClassRequestPayload);
```

Comment: Looks like `providerServiceHandler.getRequestPayload().getBusnCustomer()` returns an ArrayList, not a BCLASSRequestPayload. Do you think you should add `.get(0)` ?

Comment: yes first three lines are correct the problem starts afterwards.

Comment: I think maybe there is problem in set method

Comment: Well the problem is clearly when you cast an `ArrayList` into a `BCLASSRequestPayload`, and that is done on line 4.

Comment: so how to resolve this error

Comment: I told you: add `.get(0)` on line 4